# Using R and regex expressions to convert delimited file to csv

Tags: r, regex, csv

I am trying to convert raw weather station data from a datalogger to an easy to use csv file.  The data looks like the following.  The data comes in this space delimited format, where the first row of data has 47 columns, with the first value being equal to 111, and the 47th equal to 329.1.  The second row's first value is also 111, and the 47th is 354.2.  Not all rows have the same number of columns, and the '-' sign in front of any number means that is a negative number.

```
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  07+1.013  08+0.943
09+342.1  10+21.26  11+0.000  12+31.76  13+18.46  14+16.50  15+1800.  16+5.250
17+69.46  18+1859.  19+55.25  20+27.61  21+1808.  22+50.25  23+2.367  24+1806.
25+15.25  26+14.78  27+1859.  28+55.25  29+60.11  30+1800.  31-5.250  32+0.000
33+1854.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+1819.  37+50.25  38+14.80  39+69.40  40+0.073
41+275.3  42+0.447  43+18.29  44+22.30  45+22.43  46+2.367  47+329.1
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2000.  04-14.28  05+070.7  06+0.012  07+0.755  08+0.694
09+337.5  10+22.90  11+0.000  12+0.044  13+18.13  14+14.78  15+1900.  16+15.25
17+072.6  18+1908.  19+15.25  20+0.146  21+1946.  22+10.25  23+1.567  24+1948.
25+25.25  26+14.02  27+1959.  28+20.25  29+69.21  30+1936.  31-25.25  32+0.000
33+1900.  34+20.25  35+0.447  36+1900.  37+5.250  38+14.02  39+69.95  40+0.000
41+343.6  42+0.607  43+17.97  44+21.97  45+22.13  46+1.567  47+354.2
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617  08+0.528
09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000  12+0.026  13+17.79  14+14.02  15+2000.  16+5.250
17+082.7  18+2050.  19+55.25  20+0.146  21+2028.  22+30.25  23+1.407  24+2001.
25+25.25  26+11.78  27+2051.  28+40.25  29+69.68  30+2001.  31-25.25  32+0.000
33+2000.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+2002.  37+25.25  38+12.00  39+081.0  40+0.000
41+39.42  42+0.447  43+17.61  44+21.68  45+21.82  46+1.407  47+349.4
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617  08+0.528  
09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000
```

I am reading the data in like this:

```
test <- readLines(data)
```

This leads to a data frame with each observation consisting of a row of the data, in character format, which is not useful.  Maybe there's a way to deal with this, but I have tried many ways, with no luck.  I'm sure there's a way to get the above data read into 5 lines, each consisting of the appropriate number of columns and comma separated, and each value without the column number in front of it (shown below). But, I do not know how to do this, especially with regular expressions.  If anyone could provide help, I would be very grateful.  Thank you.

```
111,262,1900,-15.68,64.50,8.82,1.013,0.943,342.1,21.26,0,31.76,18.46,16.50,1800,5.250,69.46,1859,55.25,27.61,1808,50.25,2.367,1806,15.25,14.78,1859,55.25,60.11,1800,-5.250,0,1854,5.250,0.447,1819,50.25,14.80,69.40,0.073,275.3,0.447,18.29,22.30,22.43,2.367,329.1
111,262,2000,-14.28,70.7,0.012,0.755,0.694,337.5,22.90,0,0.044,18.13,14.78,1900,15.25,072.6,1908,15.25,0.146,1946,10.25,1.567,1948,25.25,14.02,1959,20.25,69.21,1936,-25.25,0,1900,20.25,0.447,1900,5.250,14.02,69.95,0,343.6,0.607,17.97,21.97,22.13,1.567,354.2
111,262,2100,-13.01,75.7,0.007,0.617,0.528,20.10,30.68,0,0.026,17.79,14.02,2000,5.250,082.7,2050,55.25,0.146,2028,30.25,1.407,2001,25.25,11.78,2051,40.25,69.68,2001,-25.25,0,2000,5.250,0.447,2002,25.25,12.00,081.0,0,39.42,0.447,17.61,21.68,21.82,1.407,349.4
111,262,1900,-15.68,64.50,8.82  
111,262,2100,-13.01,75.7,0.007,0.617,0.528,20.10,30.68,0  

This is what my data looks like after I read it in:
c("01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  
07+1.013       08+0.943", 
"09+342.1  10+21.26  11+0.000  12+31.76  13+18.46  14+16.50  15+1800.
16+5.250", 
"17+69.46  18+1859.  19+55.25  20+27.61  21+1808.  22+50.25  23+2.367  
24+1806.", 
"25+15.25  26+14.78  27+1859.  28+55.25  29+60.11  30+1800.  31-5.250  
32+0.000", 
"33+1854.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+1819.  37+50.25  38+14.80  39+69.40
40+0.073", 
"41+275.3  42+0.447  43+18.29  44+22.30  45+22.43  46+2.367  47+329.1", 
"01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2000.  04-14.28  05+070.7  06+0.012  07+0.755   
08+0.694", 
"09+337.5  10+22.90  11+0.000  12+0.044  13+18.13  14+14.78  15+1900. 
16+15.25", 
"17+072.6  18+1908.  19+15.25  20+0.146  21+1946.  22+10.25  23+1.567 
24+1948.", 
"25+25.25  26+14.02  27+1959.  28+20.25  29+69.21  30+1936.  31-25.25  
32+0.000", 
"33+1900.  34+20.25  35+0.447  36+1900.  37+5.250  38+14.02  39+69.95     
40+0.000", 
"41+343.6  42+0.607  43+17.97  44+21.97  45+22.13  46+1.567  47+354.2", 
"01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617 
08+0.528", 
"09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000  12+0.026  13+17.79  14+14.02  15+2000.    
16+5.250", 
"17+082.7  18+2050.  19+55.25  20+0.146  21+2028.  22+30.25  23+1.407  
24+2001.", 
"25+25.25  26+11.78  27+2051.  28+40.25  29+69.68  30+2001.  31-25.25 
32+0.000", 
"33+2000.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+2002.  37+25.25  38+12.00  39+081.0 
40+0.000", 
"41+39.42  42+0.447  43+17.61  44+21.68  45+21.82  46+1.407  47+349.4", 
"01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82", 
"01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617
08+0.528", 
"09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000")

This is the result of dput(text) after running the code:
structure(list(X01 = c(111, 342.1, 69.46, 15.25, 1854, 275.3, 
111, 337.5, 72.6, 25.25, 1900, 343.6, 111, 20.1, 82.7, 25.25, 
2000, 39.42, 111, 111, 20.1), X02 = c(262, 21.26, 1859, 14.78, 
5.25, 0.447, 262, 22.9, 1908, 14.02, 20.25, 0.607, 262, 30.68, 
2050, 11.78, 5.25, 0.447, 262, 262, 30.68), X03 = c(1900, 0, 
55.25, 1859, 0.447, 18.29, 2000, 0, 15.25, 1959, 0.447, 17.97, 
2100, 0, 55.25, 2051, 0.447, 17.61, 1900, 2100, 0), X04 = c(-15.68, 
31.76, 27.61, 55.25, 1819, 22.3, -14.28, 0.044, 0.146, 20.25, 
1900, 21.97, -13.01, 0.026, 0.146, 40.25, 2002, 21.68, -15.68, 
-13.01, NA), X05 = c(64.5, 18.46, 1808, 60.11, 50.25, 22.43, 
70.7, 18.13, 1946, 69.21, 5.25, 22.13, 75.7, 17.79, 2028, 69.68, 
25.25, 21.82, 64.5, 75.7, NA), X06 = c(8.82, 16.5, 50.25, 1800, 
14.8, 2.367, 0.012, 14.78, 10.25, 1936, 14.02, 1.567, 0.007, 
14.02, 30.25, 2001, 12, 1.407, 8.82, 0.007, NA), X07 = c(1.013, 
1800, 2.367, -5.25, 69.4, 329.1, 0.755, 1900, 1.567, -25.25, 
69.95, 354.2, 0.617, 2000, 1.407, -25.25, 81, 349.4, NA, 0.617, 
NA), X08 = c(0.943, 5.25, 1806, 0, 0.073, NA, 0.694, 15.25, 1948, 
0, 0, NA, 0.528, 5.25, 2001, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0.528, NA), X09 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
X10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X11 = c(NA_real_, 
.....)
```

Comment: use `dput(test)` in your question to show what your data looks like after you read it in

Comment: What is the original file type you are reading the data in from?

Comment: Richard, it is a .dat file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not explicit about the format of your data, but it seems as if the prefix, `nn+` of each field is the column number, which should be ignored.
If so, a simple pattern to remove that might help.  But this doesn't work for the negative numbers.

```
> line <- "01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  07+1.013  08+0.943"
> gsub("\\d\\d\\+", "", line)
[1] "0111.  0262.  1900.  04-15.68  64.50  08.82  1.013  0.943"
```

Is there any reason to keep these in the form of 5 rows with up to 47 columns, but where the number of columns can vary over rows?

Comment: I have no control over the varying number of columns by row, but it is that way because some of the rows summarize the data by hour or day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can ignore the number before the `+/-` sign and they're sequential for each line you can convert this into a data frame of numbers with the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
  as_data_frame %>% 
  separate(value, into = sprintf("X%02d", 1:47), sep = "\\s+") %>% 
  mutate_all(str_replace, pattern = "\\d{2}((\\+)|(?=\\-))", replacement = "") %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
# A tibble: 3 x 47
    X01   X02   X03    X04   X05   X06   X07   X08   X09   X10   X11    X12   X13
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1   111   262  1900 -15.68  64.5 8.820 1.013 0.943 342.1 21.26     0 31.760 18.46
2   111   262  2000 -14.28  70.7 0.012 0.755 0.694 337.5 22.90     0  0.044 18.13
3   111   262  2100 -13.01  75.7 0.007 0.617 0.528  20.1 30.68     0  0.026 17.79
# ... with 34 more variables: X14 <dbl>, X15 <dbl>, X16 <dbl>, X17 <dbl>,
#   X18 <dbl>, X19 <dbl>, X20 <dbl>, X21 <dbl>, X22 <dbl>, X23 <dbl>, X24 <dbl>,
#   X25 <dbl>, X26 <dbl>, X27 <dbl>, X28 <dbl>, X29 <dbl>, X30 <dbl>, X31 <dbl>,
#   X32 <dbl>, X33 <dbl>, X34 <dbl>, X35 <dbl>, X36 <dbl>, X37 <dbl>, X38 <dbl>,
#   X39 <dbl>, X40 <dbl>, X41 <dbl>, X42 <dbl>, X43 <dbl>, X44 <dbl>, X45 <dbl>,
#   X46 <dbl>, X47 <dbl>
```

First I separate each entry on each line into it's own column.

The next step with the regex is a bit trickier. Each + or - is preceded by two digits, so we match that. We also want to match and more a + if it's there but only match and leave in place a -. This uses a positive lookahead which matches if the string contains a - ahead of it, but doesn't include the -. I played around with the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/VvIRlu/1

After that I can mutate all the column to numeric and we're done.

Comment: Thank you, but my data is not being transformed into 3 rows, like yours is.  Mine is being kept with the same number of rows, with a bunch of NA's appended to each row.  I'm not sure what's different, since I'm using your exact code.

Comment: Could you run and then share the result of `dput(test)`?

Comment: I added the results of dput for both reading in mt data and running the code.

Comment: Oh I see now, I thought each line contained a whole row of data. Let me fix the example.

Comment: Is the number of value per line consistently 8? And does the value after `01+` always begin a line?

Comment: I believe there is always 8 values per line and yes, the value after 01 (not necessarily 01+, it could be 01-) always begins a new line of data.  Is there a way to upload a sample file on here?  The code is still not putting the data into the proper rows.  I think there's still a difference in the file formatting after it's read in.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at this by assuming that the `01` prefix indicates the start of a new case (using `str_split("^01|\n01")` and each desired column is prefixed with a two digit number preceded by a space (i.e., `str_split("\\s[0-9]{2}`).  This splits the text into separate cases.

These cases are then converted to a single `tibble` with help from `purrr::map2_df` and `tidyr::spread`.  A small modification is made at the end to put the columns in the correct order using `gtools::mixedorder`.

And to convert the data to comma separated you could write it out to a csv file. For example, just change the last line in the solution to `df %>% select(gtools::mixedorder(names(.))) %>% write_csv("df.csv")`

**Solution**

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

cases <- txt %>% 
  str_split("^01|\n01") %>% unlist() %>% 
  str_split("\\s[0-9]{2}") %>% .[-1]

df <- map2_df(cases, 1:length(cases), function(x, y) { 
  x %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    mutate(rowname = paste0("V", rowname)) %>%
    mutate(id = y)
  }) %>% spread(rowname, value) 

df %>% select(gtools::mixedorder(names(.)))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 48
#>      id    V1    V2    V3     V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11
#> * <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   111   262  1900 -15.68  64.5 8.820 1.013 0.943 342.1 21.26     0
#> 2     2   111   262  2000 -14.28  70.7 0.012 0.755 0.694 337.5 22.90     0
#> 3     3   111   262  2100 -13.01  75.7 0.007 0.617 0.528  20.1 30.68     0
#> 4     4   111   262  1900 -15.68  64.5 8.820    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 5     5   111   262  2100 -13.01  75.7 0.007 0.617 0.528  20.1 30.68     0
#> # ... with 36 more variables: V12 <dbl>, V13 <dbl>, V14 <dbl>, V15 <dbl>,
#> #   V16 <dbl>, V17 <dbl>, V18 <dbl>, V19 <dbl>, V20 <dbl>, V21 <dbl>,
#> #   V22 <dbl>, V23 <dbl>, V24 <dbl>, V25 <dbl>, V26 <dbl>, V27 <dbl>,
#> #   V28 <dbl>, V29 <dbl>, V30 <dbl>, V31 <dbl>, V32 <dbl>, V33 <dbl>,
#> #   V34 <dbl>, V35 <dbl>, V36 <dbl>, V37 <dbl>, V38 <dbl>, V39 <dbl>,
#> #   V40 <dbl>, V41 <dbl>, V42 <dbl>, V43 <dbl>, V44 <dbl>, V45 <dbl>,
#> #   V46 <dbl>, V47 <dbl>
```

**Source data**
The solution above does not attempt to split the text into lines on import using `readLines`.  Instead, `readr::read_file` should work with the proposed solution. The text `txt` used in this example was:

```r
txt <- "01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  07+1.013  08+0.943
09+342.1  10+21.26  11+0.000  12+31.76  13+18.46  14+16.50  15+1800.  16+5.250
17+69.46  18+1859.  19+55.25  20+27.61  21+1808.  22+50.25  23+2.367  24+1806.
25+15.25  26+14.78  27+1859.  28+55.25  29+60.11  30+1800.  31-5.250  32+0.000
33+1854.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+1819.  37+50.25  38+14.80  39+69.40  40+0.073
41+275.3  42+0.447  43+18.29  44+22.30  45+22.43  46+2.367  47+329.1
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2000.  04-14.28  05+070.7  06+0.012  07+0.755  08+0.694
09+337.5  10+22.90  11+0.000  12+0.044  13+18.13  14+14.78  15+1900.  16+15.25
17+072.6  18+1908.  19+15.25  20+0.146  21+1946.  22+10.25  23+1.567  24+1948.
25+25.25  26+14.02  27+1959.  28+20.25  29+69.21  30+1936.  31-25.25  32+0.000
33+1900.  34+20.25  35+0.447  36+1900.  37+5.250  38+14.02  39+69.95  40+0.000
41+343.6  42+0.607  43+17.97  44+21.97  45+22.13  46+1.567  47+354.2
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617  08+0.528
09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000  12+0.026  13+17.79  14+14.02  15+2000.  16+5.250
17+082.7  18+2050.  19+55.25  20+0.146  21+2028.  22+30.25  23+1.407  24+2001.
25+25.25  26+11.78  27+2051.  28+40.25  29+69.68  30+2001.  31-25.25  32+0.000
33+2000.  34+5.250  35+0.447  36+2002.  37+25.25  38+12.00  39+081.0  40+0.000
41+39.42  42+0.447  43+17.61  44+21.68  45+21.82  46+1.407  47+349.4
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+1900.  04-15.68  05+64.50  06+08.82  
01+0111.  02+0262.  03+2100.  04-13.01  05+075.7  06+0.007  07+0.617  08+0.528  
09+20.10  10+30.68  11+0.000  "
```